# How to do the same in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have this jQuery that automaticali calculate when is focus out of the field. I need to the the same this in JavaScript and to call the function after each page refresh. Now after each validations my calculation from the fields get lost.

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(document).on("blur", "input[type=text]", function () {
            var imekontrolebase = $(this).attr('id');
            var ime = ($(this).attr('id')).substr(12, $(this).attr('id').length);
            var n = ime.indexOf("_");
            var red = ime.substr(n+1);

            var imekol1 = "txt_OBR_P_1_1_" + red;                                    
            var imekol2 = "txt_OBR_P_1_2_" + red;
            var imekol3 = "txtKOL3_" + red;

            var txt_OBR_P_1_1 = parseFloat($('#' + imekol1).val().replace(/\,/g, '')) || 0
            var txt_OBR_P_1_2 = parseFloat($('#' + imekol2).val().replace(/\,/g, '')) || 0

            var txtKOL3 = txt_OBR_P_1_1 + txt_OBR_P_1_2;

            if (txtKOL3 === 0 || txtKOL3 === Infinity || isNaN(txtKOL3)) {                                       
                txtKOL3 = $('#' + imekol3).val("");
            }
            else {
                var ukupnoID3 = ("" + txtKOL3).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, function ($1) { return $1 + "," });
                $('#' + imekol3).val(ukupnoID3);
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

I need to create some function like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function startCalc() {
    }
</script>
```

And call it from server side after each validation.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Script", "startCalc()", True)
```

Comment: `I have this jQuery that automatically calculate ...` Calculate what

Comment: `$(function () { ...})` is `document.ready`, ultimately you can add named function inside it. What you mean by telling "*calculation from the fields get lost*"?

Comment: @moon I calculate sum of imekol1 and imekol2 in imekol3.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto on button click my calculations get lost from the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Vanilla JavaScript solution you can try this:

```js
function startCalc() {
    var root = document.documentElement || document.body;
    root.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
        var node = e.target;
        if (node.nodeName == 'input' &&
            node.getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
            var imekontrolebase = node.getAttribute('id');
            var ime = imekontrolebase.substr(12, imekontrolebase.length);
            var n = ime.indexOf("_");
            var red = ime.substr(n+1);

            var imekol1 = "txt_OBR_P_1_1_" + red;                                    
            var imekol2 = "txt_OBR_P_1_2_" + red;
            var imekol3 = "txtKOL3_" + red;

            var txt_OBR_P_1_1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById(imekol1).value.replace(/\,/g, '')) || 0
            var txt_OBR_P_1_2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById(imekol2).value.replace(/\,/g, '')) || 0

            var txtKOL3 = txt_OBR_P_1_1 + txt_OBR_P_1_2;

            if (txtKOL3 === 0 || txtKOL3 === Infinity || isNaN(txtKOL3)) {                                       
                txtKOL3 = document.getElementById(imekol3).value;
            }
            else {
                var ukupnoID3 = ("" + txtKOL3).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, function ($1) { return $1 + "," });
                document.getElementById(imekol3).value = ukupnoID3;
            }
        })

    });
}
```

basically

- `$('#name') -> document.getElementById('name');` or
- `document.querySelector('#name')` that return single element or
- `document.querySelectorAll('#name')` that return array like object
- `jqueryObject.val()` -> htmlNode.value
- `$(document).on('blur' -> node.addEventListener('blur'` and you need to check for the correct node using event.target

Comment: Nice effort @jcubic +1 - but I think you are encouraging SeaSide to rely on SO to provide such answers, without even the slightest effort shown from his side to find the solution